# why does the weight painting acts like this?

Tags: weight-painting

[The short gif of the issue I'm having](https://gfycat.com/jointmagnificenteskimodog)

when I switch to a different bone to weight paint, the previous bone that i just subtract the weight, it re-appear again?

Comment: What happens when you toggle the vertex groups from the mesh properties?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/